# Open browser at specified URL using ACTION_VIEW not working when chrome is default browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 browsers installed on my Android device 1) default and 2) Chrome

When I run the following code I get a 'Complete action using' selector...

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + query; 
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

The default Android browser works, in that a browser opens at the specified URL. However, when I open using Chrome browser, Chrome simply opens... it seems to ignore the specified URL.

Is this a problem with Chrome, or my code?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The problem was my query variable.  It appears Chrome did not accept the format of the query string, where the default Android browser did.

The get the code to work I had to URL encode the query...

```
query = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
```